# No transformation found in rviz

Tags: ros, pepper, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to setup simulated pepper in gazebo for navigation but I can't visualize any topic in map or odom frame because rviz can't find any transformation between links but my tf tree looks normal. [my rviz errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naU5J.jpg) [my tf tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uYjZ.jpg). I think the problem might be with the names of the frames because in tf tree they all have prefix pepper_robot and in rviz they are missing that prefix.
Thanks

Comment: I solved the problem just by putting tf prefix pepper_robot in rviz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the tf frames being published (by `robot_state_publisher`) don't match the frame ids being published by the sensors.

I assume you're using the [pepper-ros-stack](https://github.com/larics/pepper-ros-stack/blob/master/pepper_robot/pepper_description/launch/pepper_publisher.launch) repo (if not, it serves as a good example of what changes to make).

Somewhere, a launch file you're using probably has something that looks like below:

```xml
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="pepper_robot"/>
</node>
```

This is where the `tf_prefix` is being set and added to all your tf frames. Remove it and it should match with the frames being published by the sensors.

```xml
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm indeed using that repo. I will remove the prefix in launch file. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question: Why is the initial z coordinate in [repo_launch_file](https://github.com/larics/pepper-ros-stack/blob/master/pepper_virtual/pepper_gazebo_plugin/launch/pepper_gazebo_plugin_Y20.launch) set to 0.88 and when I try to change it robot falls right at the start of simulation?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure without digging into it more, but it seems like the origin of the Pepper URDF file is not Pepper's base, but higher up (perhaps 0.88 m above the base). So that offset just accounts for it.